# Kubernetes - No internet coming in pods

Tags: networking, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have been working in Kubernetes for a while and I have a docker image of wildfly application. In the stanalone.xml of the wildfly, the connection to datasources are defined as follows:

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/DB" pool-name="DB" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://IP:3306/DB_NAME?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;autoReconnect=true</connection-url>
                    <driver-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                    <driver>mysql</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>root</user-name>
                        <password>root</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
```

I have one worker node and 2 replicas of the same pod are running in it. But currently i observed that internet is not able to reach my pods. I am trying with

> ping google.com

It is not giving response as expected. Already I am using **LoadBalancer** services to expose the ports.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: re-demo
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer 
  selector: 
    app: re-demo
  ports:
  - port: 9575 
    targetPort: 9575
    nodePort: 32756
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
```

How can I solve this ??

Comment: how did you setup the k8s cluster? is it happening to all the pods(which is my guess)? are you using EKS/AKS/GKE or something like that? basically needs more information on how did you set this up.

Comment: For the creation of the cluster, I used the Google cloud. I created VM instances for master node and worker node. I am not using GKE. I ran kubeadm commands from master node and set up the cluster

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZMSRRzLrLeQoV7vUuh9NdIBCHbKjQVw7kQazavV5NP0/edit?usp=sharing

these are the commands i used for setting up the cluster

Comment: Internet is coming when i am using hostNetwork = true , I am able to connect to the DB, but this approach creates port conflicts when i am running more than one replica on the same node. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65084667/multiple-instance-of-same-pod-in-same-node-kubernetes

Comment: would you be able to make sure your nodes are not having outbound rule?

Comment: outbound rule?? what is that? Can you explain?? Are you asking about whether pod is able connect to outside cluster??

Comment: I'm talking about the egress rule in the node instances. is it restricted?

Comment: egress is not enabled

Comment: egress is enabled, "allow all"

Comment: Try editing [this line in flannel](https://github.com/coreos/flannel/blob/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml#L128) to your subnet that is `172.16.0.0/16`. Let me know if this helped.

Comment: okay, do i need to uninstall the cluster to edit this file?? or is there any method i can edit without uninstalling??

Comment: Just save kube-flannel.yaml on disk, edit and do `kubectl apply -f kube-flannel.yaml`. No need to uninstall anything. You may want to try uninstalling flannel when after apply it still doesn't work, and apply it one more time.

Comment: yes, it is working, i made a new cluster up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was mistake when I set up the cluster.

```
kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address 10.128.0.12 --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
```

cidr address we should give just like what we have in our **kube_flannel.yaml** file. If you want to change the ip adress in the cidr, then first make changes in the `kube_flannel.yaml` file.

Otherwise, it will result in the no internet availability of the pods. And we need to use the `hostNetwork =true` property for internet connection, but which turn prevents us some running more than one replica of same pod in the same node.